# git push fails - permissions and ssh keep alive checked - what else?

Tags: ssh, permissions, git, timeout, keepalive

I migrated my git server to a new server and now I try to push my data to the new one.

- Client: Windows, TortoiseGit
- Server: [docker git-server](https://github.com/jkarlosb/git-server-docker)

The log when trying to push

```
git.exe push --progress "originNew" master:master

Counting objects: 26735, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14502/14502), done.
Writing objects:   2% (535/26735), 32.00 KiB | 45.00 KiB/s
```

And after clicking “OK” on the dialog
 *TortoiseGitPlink Fatal Error: “Network error: software caused connection abort”* the above text changes to

```
git.exe push --progress "originNew" master:master

Counting objects: 26735, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14502/14502), done.
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (405265 ms @ 02.04.2018 12:16:21)
```

Maybe of interest:
Compressing needs ~6sec up to 99% (14430/14502), for 100% (the last ~70 items) it needs ~6 min.

---

**What I already did:**

**Permissions:**
Doing the same with a test repo with just 2 files works!

**SSH keepalive:**
I changed ssh_config on client to include

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 25
    ServerAliveCountMax 40
```

This should send a packet every 25 seconds (max 40 times), so if my ssh connection to the git server is idle it should be kept alive for ~16min.

**HDs:**
Enough space on client and server

---

**Questions:**

1. Any other ideas how to push my data to the new server?
2. Any other ideas on what could cause this besides permissions and idle connections?
3. How can I check if the ssh_config file I changed is the right one? (used by TortoiseGit). I changed 'C:\Program Files\Git\etc\ssh' (only one found)
4. Can I somehow investigate who closes the ssh connection?
5. Which log files on client and server could help to find the problem? Any verbose/debug flags I could switch on?

Comment: Is the disk full or out of inodes on either system?

Comment: Thx, no, both client and server have enough space. Regarding inodes (something new for me) I guess there should not be a problem as the server (docker host) is fresh and pretty empty and the container should be as well

Comment: Can you try setting up a git server (non-docker) to isolate the problem to either client side or server side?

Comment: Thanks for the idea but it's finally working. Added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I fixed the issue, **unfortunately I did not find out what the problem was**. But maybe it inspires someone with a similar issue.

**What I did**:
Instead of pushing from client-side to the new server:

- I generated keys on the old server and pushed from there
- I cloned the repo from the new server to a new temporary repo on the client
- I pushed the changes from the old client-repo to the temp client repo
  (There were changes I could not push to the old server anymore.
  Unfortunately I don't remember if I tried to push from the old client
  side repo to the new server)
- then I finally pushed those changes from the temp to the new server repo

Now everything works. I can finally pull and push from the (old and new) client side repo to the new server and it's very fast. In the meanwhile I have deleted that new client side repo.

The compressing part that lasted so long before was now very fast. Maybe something like repack would have helped?!

Good luck